# how to make a drop down menu horizontal

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

Im not sure if this is possible but, I have a button called fruits. When I click on it, 4 fruit buttons appear vertically down, but I want them to appear horizontally instead?

Any ideas or hints as to how would I go about doing this?

Please don't say "try this yourself, were not here to do this for you"..I have been and I am clueless. All I am looking for is a hint, not expecting anyone to code it for me. Thanks :)

html

```
<div id="myNav" class="overlay">
        <!-- Button to close the overlay navigation -->
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
        <!-- Overlay content -->
        <div class="overlay-content"> 
            <button class="dropbtn btn-circle overlay-icon" onclick='myFunction()'>Fruits</button>
            <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <button class="dropbtn btn-circle overlay-icon">Apple</button>
                        <button class="dropbtn btn-circle overlay-icon">Banana</button>
                        <button class="dropbtn btn-circle overlay-icon">Orange</button>
                        <button class="dropbtn btn-circle overlay-icon">Pear</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

js

```
 <script>
    /* When the user clicks on the button, 
    toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
    }

    // Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
    window.onclick = function(event) {
      if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
          var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
          if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
            openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
          }
        }
      }
    }
    </script>
```

css

```
.overlay-icon { 
  float: center;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 600px 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  border-radius: 36px;
  margin-left: 660px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    font-size: 10px;  
    margin-left: 0px;
}

.dropdown-content dropbtn {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Is dropdown opening?

Comment: yes it works but the 4 items appear vertically down

Comment: I am getting error in fiddle... can you create fiddle for this...

Comment: im sorry the overlay doesnt work on fiddle

Comment: Do you want like this https://jsfiddle.net/rahul8590/zc8he0te/

Comment: yes exactly like that! thank you. I am having trouble seeing what u changed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143349/discussion-between-phantom-and-rgoat).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make the display of buttons as inline-block.
Here is the css code:

```
.dropdown-content dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change in Your css, I have removed `margin-left` and change `padding` to `60px 0` from `600px 0`

CSS:

```
.overlay-icon { 
  float: center;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 60px 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  border-radius: 36px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.show {
   display: initial;
}
```